# Webpack – rewrite CSS URLs

Tags: css, webpack

I'm using Webpack to process my CSS files. I want to rewrite `url()`s in CSS files to keep referencing the original assets, just changing the URL.

For example this file:

```
/* src/main.css */
body {
    background-image: url('image.png');
}
```

should compile to this

```
/* bundle/main.css */
body {
    background-image: url('../src/image.png');
}
```

I found the [rewrite-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) but this just does not work at all for me, it does nothing.

I've got the feeling that [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) may be able to do just what I want to do but I can't figure out how.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3):

That was actually really easy.

1. I had to set Webpack's [`context`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context) option to point to my project root.
2. Then I could easily just use file-loader like this: `file?emitFile=false&name=[path][name].[ext]&publicPath=../`.

Answer (score 0):

For Webpack 2 and Webpack 3:

```
use: [{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
  },
},
```

For a full answer with example and explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931670/1049693