# Unexpected [path] in file-loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

For my image location: `/src/assets/bitmap/sample.jpg`

Given are the key configurations:

`context: resolve('src')`

```
output: {
  path: resolve('builds/web'),
  publicPath: '',
  filename: ifProd('[name].[chunkHash].js', '[name].js')
},
```

...

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)/,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'
  }
]
```

I am expecting output structure for the image that looks like this:

`/builds/web/assets/bitmap/sample.jpg`

Instead, I get this:

`/builds/web/src/assets/bitmap/sample.jpg`

How do I tell the file-loader that output path needs to be relative to `/src` and not `/`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @pilau don't remember. sorry

Comment: Thanks. I think, finally, after 2 days, I figured it out: the `context` option for `file-loader` is responsible for how the loader builds the relative paths. Meaning: `context` = the root folder in the src directory from which to replicate the relative paths in the resulting build directory.

Comment: @pilau you are completely right. I had done the same thing. Put it in an answer so it can help people :}

Comment: I definitely will but on next Tuesday, after I come back from my long needed vacation! :)

Comment: @pilau go crazy :}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After 2 days of trial and error (Thanks Webpack docs!) I found out that there's a way to control file-loader's output and replicate the file structure of the **source** directory in the **output** directory. It's the Webpack setting `context`, which can be used per loader as well as per build.

Here's an example for file-loader:

```
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      context: <path>, // The directory to draw relative paths from
      name: '[path][name].[ext]'
    },
  },
```

Let's dive deeper into how it works.

Say we're trying to load an image via `www.website.com/assets/images/user.png`, and our project's file structure is:

```
project/
├── src/
│   └── assets/
│       └── images/
│           └── user.png
└── build/
```

The desired result would be:

```
project/
├── src/
│   └── assets/
│       └── images/
│           └── user.png
└── build/
    └── assets/
        └── images/
            └── user.png
```

The configuration for this is:

```
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      name: '[path][name].[ext]'
    },
  },
```

And that is because you want to replicate the file structure under `src` folder inside the `build` folder.

If you wanted to remove the `assets` directory from the path, the value for `context` would be: `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets')`, and file-loader will replicate the relative paths starting in 'src/assets' instead, and the result would be:

```
project/
├── src/
│   └── assets/
│       └── images/
│           └── user.png
└── build/
    └── images/
        └── user.png
```

Comment: thank you so much. You saved me few more days trying to fix these urls in my scss.

Comment: @kirill.buga Sure. It took me a while to figure this one out... I know the frustration